# Will using <ul> tags in cards result in seo penalty?

Tags: html

I have always liked using **ul** on anything that considerably seems like a list. (E.g. Shopping Card Items for goods on a eCommerce Website.)

Although recently I had been told from another developer that I should avoid ul with things like cards and only use it for text list as I will get a seo penalty for it and should use a div instead.

e.g bootstrap: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/

Has anyone had an issue with this or know about the seo penalty? I've tried looking for it but haven't found it yet. Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A Googler has confirmed that the future penalty of the engine will not concern the sites, but the pages abusing the interstitials.

Last week, Google announced a new penalty, which will be launched next January against intrusive interstitials on mobile.

The engine gave several examples of what it wanted to sanction (see below), and it is clearly the interstitials covering too much content that are in its line of sight, although there are some logical exceptions (see also The official examples given below).

Professionals could suspect it, but a Googler confirmed on Twitter that this penalty was not going to concern the SEO of a site, but only the page displaying the interstitial abusive.

For the record, in the blog announcing the new penalty, Google had written that "to improve the mobile experience, after January 10, 2017, pages on which content is not readily accessible from the engine could go back up the results".

Comment: Please add some references.

Comment: What references are you referring to in your answer?